# Tikz: two labels on one edge (one following the other one)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I would like to add a label which follows another one. For instance, I have:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\GraphInit[vstyle = Shade]

\tikzset{
  LabelStyle/.style = { rectangle, rounded corners, draw,
                        minimum width = 2em, fill = yellow!50,
                        text = red, font = \bfseries },
  VertexStyle/.append style = { inner sep=5pt,
                                font = \Large\bfseries},
  EdgeStyle/.append style = {->, bend left} }




\title{test}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{graph}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \SetGraphUnit{4}
        \Vertex{A}
        \EA(A){B}
        \Edge[label = first](A)(B)
        \Edge[label = ok](B)(A)
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have another label "second" after the "first" one on the same edge.

Comment: I modify, this is the tkz-graph package. Sorry to omit that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure Ti*k*Z, but "import" styles of `tkz-graph`. You can still use `tkz-graph` in the rest of your document. Most importantly, in this particular picture (where I don't use `tkz-graph`), I suggest not using global options (`EdgeStyle`, `LabelStyle`, etc.) to avoid conflicts. I used `labelonpath` or `myvertex` instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  labelonpath/.style = { rectangle, rounded corners, draw,
                        minimum width = 2em, fill = yellow!50,
                        text = red, font = \bfseries },
  myvertex/.style = {circle,inner sep=5pt,font = \Large\bfseries,draw,ball color=orange},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\node[myvertex] (a) {A};
\node[myvertex,right=5cm of a] (b) {B};
\draw[double=orange,double distance=1pt,line width=0.8pt,color=black,->,bend left] (a) to node[pos=.3,sloped,labelonpath] {First} node[pos=.7,sloped,labelonpath] {Second} (b);
\draw[double=orange,double distance=1pt,line width=0.8pt,color=black,->,bend left] (b) to node[midway,sloped,labelonpath] {Okay} (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]